# Image Control Bind Generated Imageurl

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, xaml

Hey there this is my first question in here, because i really don't find an answer for my Problem. Normally i check forums, google and all that stuff 5 times but in this case i don't found any solution, because i don't got the keywords i guess....

The Problem:
I got an Image Control in my WP7-App and trying to put in an Uri that looks like this:

http://veranstaltungen.meinestadt.de/images/image.php?origin=events&mode=G&id=71080093

The Problem is that this Image is not loaded by the Control. Images like this,

http://www.design-center.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/IMG_1113.jpg-mini.jpg

are loaded without any problems.

Any idea for a workaround or another control?

Thx in advance

```
<DataTemplate>
      <controls:PivotItem Margin="0,0,0,0">
             <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                    <StackPanel Name="contentPanel"  Margin="12,0,12,0">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="PartyTitle" Text="{Binding title}" Margin="10,0,0,10" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <Image x:Name="PartyImage" Source="{Binding imgUrl}" Margin="10,0,0,10" ></Image>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="PartyDescription" Margin="10,0,0,10"  Text="{Binding text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            <Button x:Name="PartyLink" DataContext="{Binding urls[0]}" Content="Link" Click="PartyLink_Click"></Button>
                    </StackPanel>
             </ScrollViewer>
      </controls:PivotItem>
</DataTemplate>
```

The Binding and stuff is working well for all controls.

Comment: could you share your xaml code that is showing the images?

Answer (score 0):

You could download the image in code behind and set it as the source. Ill post an example.

This should work but my network adapter isn't working on the emulator. Its always something.

```
  WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.leenwallpapers.com/images/gallery/funny0152.jpg");
         req.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(test), null);
```

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;

```
        // End the operation
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(ar);
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        img.SetSource(postStream);
        imgtest.Source = img;
```

In this case imgtest is the x:name of a image control in my xaml. You could of course do this in a viewmodel and imgtest could be a bitmapimage property you set and raise property changed on.